# How add location to post using FB Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How I can input location parameter to post using fb graph api:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ormr403s2dg4a6h/Facebook%202014-07-18%2014-20-38%202014-07-18%2014-21-04.jpg

Comment: We can enter special property `place: 'location-id'` to post object:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can enter special property `place: 'location-id'` to post object:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post